# java show error all java packages

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package com.icodx.domore.qms.agent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
```

this is my code
its show  all are red lines  even **import java.util.List;**  this line also

Comment: Do you have Java linked with your project? Check your Build Path for it.

Comment: Can you provide the error description?

Comment: in eclipse its show read lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check build path is properly poinintg to JDK path. (right click on project -> build path )

Restart your ecliplse from command prompt using "eclipse.exe-clean" command

Comment: iam useing ubuntu and i cant find JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY

Comment: Are you sure about java is installed on your machine?
Can you execute java -version command on terminal and see you are getting java version or not?

Comment: oits installed java -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: can you right click on project inside eclipse and select build path. then go to Configure build path and then Libraries tab.Over there you should get JRE system library entry. Make sure it is pointing to correct JRE.